# Built-in code analysers vs NuGet packages

Tags: visual-studio-2019, stylecop, static-code-analysis, roslyn-code-analysis, roslynator

Having just switched to VS2019 I’m exploring whether to use code analysis. In the project properties, “code analysis” tab, there are numerous built-in Microsoft rule sets, and I can see the editor squiggles when my code violates one of these rules. I can customise these rule sets and “save as” to create my own.

I have also seen code analyser NuGet packages such as “Roslynator” and “StyleCop.Analyzers”. What’s the difference between these and the built-in MS rules? Is it really just down to more comprehensive sets of rules/more choice?

If I wanted to stick with the built-in MS rules, are there any limitations? E.g. will they still get run and be reported on during a TFS/Azure DevOps build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ## What's the difference between legacy FxCop and FxCop analyzers?
>
> Legacy FxCop runs post-build analysis on a compiled assembly. It runs as a separate executable called FxCopCmd.exe. FxCopCmd.exe loads the compiled assembly, runs code analysis, and then reports the results (or diagnostics).
>
> FxCop analyzers are based on the .NET Compiler Platform ("Roslyn"). You install them as a NuGet package that's referenced by the project or solution. FxCop analyzers run source-code based analysis during compiler execution. FxCop analyzers are hosted within the compiler process, either csc.exe or vbc.exe, and run analysis when the project is built. Analyzer results are reported along with compiler results.
>
> ## Note
>
> You can also install FxCop analyzers as a Visual Studio extension. In this case, the analyzers execute as you type in the code editor, but they don't execute at build time. If you want to run FxCop analyzers as part of continuous integration (CI), install them as a NuGet package instead.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/fxcop-analyzers-faq?view=vs-2019

So, the built-in legacy FxCop and NuGet analyzers only run at build time while the extension analyzers can run at the same time the JIT compiler does as you type. Also, you have to specifically say to run legacy code analysis on build, whereas the NuGet analyzers will run on build just because they are installed. And analyzers installed as NuGet or extensions won't run when you go to the menu option "Run Code Analysis".

At least, that's what I get out of that page.

There's a link near the bottom of that page that takes you to what code analysis rules have moved over to the new analyzers, including rules that are now deprecated.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/fxcop-rule-port-status?view=vs-2019

The different analyzers attempt to cover different coding styles and things Microsoft didn't cover when they built FxCop. With the little research I just did on this, there's a whole rabbit hole to follow, Alice, that would take more time than I have right now to devote to it. And it seems to be filled with lots of arcane knowledge and OCD style code nitpicks that make Wonderland seem normal. But that's just my opinion.

There's lots of personal and professional opinion about various rules in these and basic Microsoft rules, so there's plenty of room to use what you want and disable what you don't. For a beginner, I'd suggest turning on only a few rules at a time. That way you aren't inundated with more warnings and errors than lines of code you might have. Ok, so that might be a bit of an exaggeration, but there's so many rules that really are nitpicks, especially on legacy code, that they aren't really worth it to have enabled, since you likely won't have time to fix it all. You will also want to do basic research and use "common sense" when you decide what to enable. ("Do I really need to worry about variable capitalization coding style consistency on an app that's been ported into 4 different languages over 15+ years and has 10k files?") This is both personal and professional opinion here, so follow it or not.

And don't forget the rules that contradict each other. Those are fun to deal with.......

Comment: Comprehensive answer thanks. I've been using StyleCop (the exe) for years in VS2013, but having finally upgraded to VS2019 I wanted to bring some of these tools up to date. I'm undecided whether to go with the StyleCop NuGet analyser or try and stick with the MS rules - there's a lot of crossover and the latter may just be enough. Also, having to install NuGet packages to do this sort of thing just doesn't sit right with me, especially when I have many solutions, each with many projects that I need to upgrade.

Comment: @AndrewStephens, yeah, I guess I don't understand why it has to be added to every project, either. If they wanted to make things easier to get updates on the rules, they could just make VS easier to upgrade, rather than waiting an hour for it to download and install updates, then restart, maybe twice. Ok, so maybe it allows other people to develop Rules as well, but those could be extensions, like they already have, and just make them run like the built-in rules. There just seems to be better ways to do it than they way MS is doing it. Maybe they need feedback.

Comment: @AndrewStephens I know this conversation is old, but as mentioned in the documentation link in the answer the bug advantage of the nuget package route is that the analyzers run at build time so can be integrated into a CI pipeline. With the VSIX that's not so feasible. Also it makes it so that individual developers on your team don't have to know which extensions to install, it's all handled by the nuget package restore.